# Woocommerce REST API - filter orders by date_paid

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm looking for a solution to filter orders by date_paid in woocommerce REST API. I can filter them by date created, or date completed, but I didn't find any way to search by paid_dates.

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue too, after searching on the internet, reading [woocommerce docs](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#list-all-orders), and trying out it seems that you can't filter the orders with **date_paid** property. You have to use the **before** and **after** properties